# Angular $watch array and update from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm deep watching an array called `$scope.route.waypoints` using the following:

```
$scope.$watch('route.waypoints',  _.debounce(function (prev, cur) {
    if(!$scope.initialized) return;
    $scope.saveRoute(true);
    console.log('route waypoints DEEP check');
}, 500), true)
```

in my `saveRoute` method I `PUT` the collection to the server.

What I want to do is upon return from the server I want to update some properties in my waypoints collection again. But when I update using the following:

```
if(data.linked && data.linked.waypoints.length){
        $scope.route.waypoints = data.linked.waypoints;
}else{
        $scope.route.waypoints = [];
}

$scope.route.days = data.routes[0].days;
```

the $watch is called again and the whole thing starts over again. 
How can I avoid that? I tried using $scope flags but it seems they are ignored again. it's all a bit of a mess now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved this by throwing away the $watches in general. After reading this excellent article: http://www.benlesh.com/2013/10/title.html I dediced to move all to ng-change directives and execute when necessary. The $watches introduced a non-testable magic that was the origin of my problem, it was just not readable anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different variables vor this data. For example for data which are coming from server you can use

```
$scope.route.waypoints
```

and for your local domain data you can use another domain, for example:

```
$scope.route.waypointsData
```

And in that case you will have the more controll because your server data and your local data will be seperated

**UPDATE 1**

so my suggestion IS

```
$scope.$watch('route.waypoints',  _.debounce(function (prev, cur) {
  //update data in this place  $scope.route.waypointsData 
}, 500), true)
```

then also turn watcher on

```
$scope.$watch('route.waypointsData ',  _.debounce(function (prev, cur) {
  // do your PUT method in that place 
}, 500), true)
```

and in ng-repeat use waypointsData. You are syncing data between models manually.

Comment: Yeah but I need this one waypoints collection because it is used for displaying in the interface. It's an ng-repeat of all those waypoints on a map as well as a sidebar. I think it will get much more complicated when I do it like you suggest. Also, upon next edit of this waypoint I want the collection to be updated again, and again..

Comment: in view you can use your waypointsData , and when $scope.route.waypoints fired you can update your local data

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand what you mean. I use waypointsData for ng-repeat/ng-model and then $watch(waypoints). But I also want to trigger an update to the server when the user edits the waypoint in the interface. So in that case I should also watch waypointsData which then updates `waypoints` again. Which results in the same problem right?

Comment: no you can update server in waypointsData watcher, and waypoints will be responsible only for updating data from server

Comment: sorry man but I don't get it. Can you maybe update your answer to make clear what you mean? How can I watch(wpData) and then only update waypoints on return when that should be represented in the same array?

Comment: let me clarify , your waypoints  watchers fires when your reciving data from server yes ? and also when user edit something from view

Comment: Yes. So the problem is isolated to this: A user can add a waypoint to a route, so he updates the waypoint collection. Then it is put to the server, the server fills in some fields of this waypoint that I want to show to the user again, so I want to update the just-added waypoint again.